# Is there any alternative to lambda in mpmath.nsum()?

Tags: python, lambda, mpmath

I was using `mpmath's nsum()` function for summation operation from 1 to inf.
like this
but lambda is one line function and my equations are so long
like 
∑_(n=1)^∞▒e^(〖-n〗^2 )/(n^2+ 4〖(a-b)〗

for simple one line summation equations it works but for long summations how to use it?
Is there any way by which we can give long summation equations to the `nsum()` function?

```
import mpmath
mpmath.mp.dps = 50
nsum(lambda x: exp(-x**2), [-inf, inf])
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything that implements the `__call__` method could be used:

Either a `lambda`:

```
nsum(lambda x: exp(-x**2), [-inf, inf])
```

Or a `def` function:

```
def exp_sum(x):
    return exp(-x**2)
nsum(exp_sum, [-inf, inf])
```

Or a `class`

```
class exp_sum:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __call__(self,x):
        return exp(-x**2)

nsum(exp_sum(), [-inf, inf])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute a normal function for the lambda:

```
def func(x):
    return exp(-x ** 2)

nsum(func, [-inf, inf])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Can we use it for very long summation equations